# Is it possible change the activity that is shown when switching apps on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In an Android device, when I click to switch apps, I can see details of last activity visited of each app.

Is it possible to choose a different activity for this case?

I tried to change the activity and applying a blur to the current one on Application `onActivityPause()` method, but both changes are applied only after `onActivityResume()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean to the snapshot that is displayed when clicking on recent apps button, you can customize it as you like using [`onCreateThumbnail()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas)) method at activity class. You can provide any bitmap you like and return `true` in order to tell the system to use your provided image instead of the default activity captured the screenshot.

EDIT:

unfortunately, seems it's not supported anymore and [not working since android 4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370), the only thing that can be done is to obscure the contents of the activity from recents dialog, by using this flag:
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE

Comment: I overrided `onCreateThumbnail()` but it's never called. Do I need to do something else? I'm debugging on API 23.

Comment: answered above in the edit of the answer, it's not supported anymore